# Significado de "rola" en Hispanoamérica

Tags: significado, méxico

El otro día vi unos cuántos vídeos de *Héroes del Silencio* en YouTube y me llamó la atención ver muchos comentarios como:

> pinche **rolon** con esa **rola** mi novia y yo [...]
>
> chingon **rola** una de mis preferidas
>
> Super **rolon** y achingar su puta madre kien no le guste
>
> Esta **rola** y marihuana la mejor combinación.
>
> pura nostalgia .y varias mujeres y  cawamas me acompañaron oyendo esta muy buena **rola**
>
> [En respuesta a otro usuario] así que tú eres el artista de esa **rola**?!
>
> pinche **rolotona**

Salvo el primero, todos los comentarios son de [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_akgbPNWBUY), por si alguien necesita más contexto.

Por un lado me parecería que `rola`  significa canción, pero por el otro parece que `rolar` significase `molar` o `gustar`. ¿Quizá son dos términos diferentes?

Comment: El _Diccionario de americanismos_ te confirma que _[rola](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=rola)_ significa "canción, composición musical" en México. Creo que todas las palabras en negrita hacen referencia a lo mismo: "rolón" = "cancionaza", "temazo", y "rolotona" tres cuartos de lo mismo.

Comment: A los mexicanos nos encanta buscar el sentido más rebuscado para encontrar humor en el doble sentido de la palabra. Curiosamente también refiriéndose a las canciones. Héroes del silencio, no falta quien exclame "Mum bolita mágica!" (conocida marca de desodorante femenino, con aplicador esférico o "de bolita" propiamente un "roll-on" o bien, tremendo **rolón** como *la chispa adecuada.* =)

Comment: Cambio el tag hispanoamerica por México porque esa palabra aplica principalmente para ese país.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El Diccionario de americanismos nos resuelve la duda:

> [**rola**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=n8LGI6K2Zx0A1tANUpN%7Cwzwy3Plqpx0Amidd0qe).
>   I.  1.  f. Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni. Canción, composición musical. pop.

Si hacemos el ejercicio de sustituir la palabra en las frases que indicas, parece que todo encaja:

> pinche **rolon** con esa **rola** mi novia y yo [...]  →
>   pinche **cancionzaza** con esa **canción** mi novia y yo [...]
>
> pinche **rolotona**  →
>   pinche **canción**

En el sentido que *rolón*, *rolotona* y demás son derivados superlativos de *rola*, de la misma forma que *cancionzaza* u otras que podamos utilizar.

Es decir, en México, Guatemala, Honduras, El Salvador y Nicaragua, *rola* quiere decir canción.

Es también interesante ver la gran cantidad de significados coloquiales que tiene *rolar*:

> [**rolar(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=qEovEsfnFx0AIekiitA).
>   I.  1.  tr. Mx. Poner algo en circulación, difundirlo. pop + cult → espon.
>   II. 1.  intr. ES. Liar cigarrillos de marihuana. drog.
>   2.  tr. prnl. Ho. Fumar marihuana. drog.
>   3.  tr. Ni. Hacer cigarros puros, tabacos.
>   III.    1.  intr. Ch. En Derecho, estar una actuación o prueba reflejadas en un expediente con indicación de la hoja en que se encuentra.
>   IV. 1.  intr. Gu. Pasear, dar una vuelta o caminata.
>   V.  1.  intr. prnl. Bo:E,O. Tener trato o amistad con alguien. pop + cult → espon.
>   VI. 1.  tr. ES. Pasar algo de mano en mano.
>   VII.    1.  tr. Pa. Apretar o allanar tierra o grava, por medio de una rola.

Sin olvidar una palabra característica de Colombia:

> **rolo, -a**.
>   I.  1.  adj. Co. Relativo a la ciudad de Bogotá.

Comment: Interesante que el DRAE recogiese [rola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WdHEAUn) y [rolar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wcjdmpm) pero con ninguna de las acepciones del de americanismos. Simpre pensé que el de americanismos era más específico, pero que el DRAE lo englobaba todo.

Answer (score 3):

En efecto, ***rola*** es la forma coloquial de referirse a una canción.

Tal vez en el sentido en que la música se comparte o se va pasando de voz en voz. Es probable también  que tenga que ver con el anglicismo *"Rock and roll"*

Por otro lado, si se usa como verbo, adquiere el significado es *compartir* con una fuerte connotación a que quien se beneficia de tu generosidad comparta, a su vez con un tercero, y así hasta que todo el grupo haya participado del objeto o bien que se está "rolando"

Visualizando el ceremonial de cebar mate en comunidad, en México diríamos que se *rolan* el mate o lo van pasando a turnos.

En esta acepción, tal vez su origen proviene de *"pasar roll call"* o lista, aunque se antoja más como coincidencia entre rock and roll y roll call, muy afortunada al incluir la connotación de compartir.

A reserva  de alguna referencia con autoridad al respecto, es la forma en que usamos "rola" y "rolar" en México.

---

Un tercer significado, sobre todo hablando de béisbol, una pelota que en vez de ser lanzada por el aire, se desplaza rodando por el suelo es una *"rola"* o pelota *"rolita"* ya sea que el lanzador la entregue de esta manera al bateador en una estrategia para "regalar" la base, pues una pelota lanzada de esta  manera nunca calificará como **strike**

También aplica si este es el efecto que adquiere la bola después de batearla con un toque del bat en lugar del abanico completo, obligando al lanzador y primera base o lanzador y tercera base a abandonar sus puestos para capturar la pelota en juego. Se dice entonces que se *"bateó una rola"*

Este uso del vocablo proviene sin lugar a duda del término inglés *Rolling ball* que es como se denomina este desplazamiento de la pelota en tanto concierne al *"rey de los deportes"*

De ahí viene el modismo béisbolero de *"solo lanza rolitas"* que se dice de alguien que no pone suficiente empeño en su oficio o responsabilidad.

Comment: Interesante. En España diríamos "rular" ("que _rule_") para compartir, plan "que circule entre el grupo" ese vaso de mini, ese porrro, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Rolar = Dar vueltas o circular.
En la música hace referencia al hecho de que principalmente en los discos de acetato y seguidamente en los más compactos y portables "casetes", el soporte había de ponerse a girar para reproducir la música grabada en él. .. De ésa forma había que poner a rolar el disco o el casete para escuchar la melodía contenida en él.